# Could not instantiate managed bean directly with liquibase diff command

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I am trying to generate a change log using `mvn liquibase:diff -Dliquibase.changeLogFile=/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml -X -Dliquibase.outputChangeLogFile=/db/changelog/changes/v0.2-10.11.2023-changelog.sql` but I am getting Could not instantiate managed bean directly along with NoSuchMethodException: com.app.model.dbUtils.AttributeEncryptor.() for my converter class.

```
@Component
@Converter
public class AttributeEncryptor implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

    private final Key key;
    private final Cipher cipher;

    @Value(value = "${encryption.key}")
    String encryptionKey;

    public AttributeEncryptor() {
        key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(attribute.getBytes()));
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(dbData)));
        } catch (InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```